# html таблицы rowspan

Tags: html, table

Мне необходимо сделать такую таблицу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но получается так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю, в чём ошибаюсь

```css
.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table td,
.table th {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">
        Форма для отправки фотографии на сайт
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <th rowspan="5">Автор фотографии</th>
      <td rowspan="2">Фамилия И.О.</td>
      <td rowspan="2">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Введите ваше имя">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Пол</td>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="">
          Женский
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="">
          Мужской
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Страна</td>
      <td>
        <select name="country">
          <option value="Россия">Россия</option>
          <option value="США">США</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Я думал, что линии нужно так раставить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример

по колонкам

`1 tbody row` - `td(rowspan5) td           td`

`2 tbody row` -              `td(rowspan2) td`

`3 tbody row` -                           `td`

`4 tbody row` -              `td           td`

```css
.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.table td,
.table th {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.td-family {
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">
        Форма для отправки фотографии на сайт
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4"><strong>Автор фотографии</strong></td>
      <td class="td-family">Фамилия И.О.</td>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="Введите ваше имя"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Пол</td>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="">
          Женский
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="">
          Мужской
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Страна</td>
      <td>
        <select name="country">
          <option value="Россия">Россия</option>
          <option value="США">США</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: сделал на 3 ```colspan="3"``` - это не играет роль, главное чтобы на остальных колонках в сумме также было

Comment: У меня поле Фамилия И.О. должно быть такого же размера, как Пол. Я пытаюсь поправить, но получается также, как у меня изначально было

Comment: @Михаил Камахин - добавил описание

Comment: Благодарю, но у меня всё равно не получается сделать так, чтобы Фамилия И.О. были такого же размера, как Пол

Comment: @Михаил Камахин - обновил

Comment: Да, но у тебя два input введите ваше имя 

Comment: @Михаил Камахин -  размер колонки можно изменить используя ```css``` или ```js```

Comment: Тут как раз задача базово на html

Comment: @Михаил Камахин - эти ряды никак не связаны

Comment: я обновил описание, я неправильно думал?